# How to edit the "hitbox" of an image using getBoundingClientRect();

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have an image floating around a page and I need to make it so when it hits something, something happens. While doing this, I used the getBoundingClientRect(); in order to find the position of the image to find when it hits. Annoyingly, the position of the image is about 100 px off (not exact) from what it shows online. How do I fix this?

I've already attempted to change this height/width elements of the image, it hasn't worked.

```
 <!dOcTyPe HtMl>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
 scale=1">
 <style>
 span{
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    border-radius: 13px;
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
    }
   #myDiv{
    max-width: 100px;
    }
    #eve{
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    background-color: white;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 3px gray solid;
    }
    .body{
    background-color: black;
    }
     .circimg{
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background: none;

    }
    #dot{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    }
    </style>
  <body class="body">
  <audio id="audio" 
  src="http://www.willmargulies.com/gimn_rf_t3- 
   [AudioTrimmer.com].mp3" autoplay="false" ></audio>
   <img id="dot" class="circimg" top="0px" 
   src="https://www.willmargulies.com/PinClipart.com_label- 
   clipart_183729.png">
    <script>
   function playSound() {
      var sound = document.getElementById("audio");
      sound.play();
      }
    </script>
  <script>
    document.getElementsByTagName("img").top = "50px";

  var div = document.getElementById("dot");
  var x = 0
  var lr = 1;
  var concise = 1;
  var y = 0;
  var he = window.innerWidth - 50;
  var inwit = window.innerWidth - 30;
  var inhei = window.innerHeight - 15;
   function func(){

  div.style.top = y + "px";     
  div.style.left = x + "px"; 

  if(div.style.left === he + "px"){lr = 0;}
  if(div.style.left === "20px"){lr = 1;}
  if(lr === 1){x = x + 1}else{x = x - 1}

  if(div.style.top === inhei + "px"){concise = 0;}
  if(div.style.top === "15px"){concise = 1;}
  if(concise === 1){y = y + 1}
  else{y = y - 1}

  if(div.style.left === "0" && div.style.top === "0px"){
  playSound();
  }



  var span1 = document.getElementById("dot");
  var button = document.getElementById("eve");

  var rect1 = span1.getBoundingClientRect();
  var rect2 = button.getBoundingClientRect();

  var overlap = (rect1.right == rect2.left ||  
  rect1.left == rect2.right ||                
  rect1.bottom == rect2.top ||                 
  rect1.top == rect2.bottom)                  

  if(overlap){
  alert("holy bjesus")
  }

        }



   setInterval(func, 5);

  </script>
  <center>
     <button id="eve" class="" onClick="if(touches(span, btn))                                    
   {alert('k');}">Putin The Bootin</button>
  </center></body>
```

Comment: What do you mean -  if someone click on element it's clicked, so just make it bigger. If you want to also trigger same action if mouse is close to this button, find another way eg. trigger this event also if mouse clicks this button's parent.

Comment: @Zydnar I wanted to trigger an action when the image and button were touching

Comment: First use CSS prop `box-sizing: border-box` for all elements - so padding and border will be counted into elements size. Also set body margin to 0.

Comment: @Zydnar Still counts as larger than it shows. If you want to see a visual with your suggestions implemented, the repo is willmargulies.com/circpic.htm . Any other ideas?

Comment: button is 300 x 115 - it counts well. And getBoundingClientRect shows position from top left corner.

Comment: I know what is wrong - you are using sprite and you count this little point as it was whole image, but it's not. This is what is too large not the button.

Comment: @Zydnar so the image is too large? How do I fix this?